# get all entities with the same field values

Tags: hibernate, hql, jhipster

I have two entities , Produit and Projet.
Produit is related to Projet with the relationship manyToOne 
I am trying to get all the Products with the same ProjetId
so i've created in ProduitResource the fucntion:

```
@GetMapping("/produits/projet/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProduitDTO>> getAllProjetProducts(@PathVariable Long id,Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Produits");
        Page<ProduitDTO> page = produitService.findAllByProjetProducts(id,pageable);
       HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
in produitService

 /**
     * Get all the produits.
     *
     * @param pageable the pagination information.
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     * @return the list of entities.
     */
    Page<ProduitDTO> findAllByProjetProducts(Long id,Pageable pageable);

and in ProduitRepository:
@Query("from ProduitDTO WHERE projetId = ?1")
    Page<ProduitDTO> findAllByProjectId(Long id,Pageable pageable);
but when i add to ProduitServiceImp 
@Override
    public Page<ProduitDTO> findAllByProjectProducts(Long id, Pageable pageable) {

       return produitRepository.findAllByProjectId(id, pageable).map(produitMapper::toDto);

    }
```

Following is the error I am getting :"type mismatche , cannot convert from Page to Page!!"

Comment: I have tried my best to edit your question. Please take some time to read the article here- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post by providing more details on your problem statement and situation.

Comment: Make sure you are using `org.springframework.data.domain.Page`  everywhere